# Parse JSON file failed in JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I am trying to Access to type (Lower square marked) without success

my code falls in the beginning (when I check the length) :

```
Object.data.ServiceData.modelObjects.length;
```

(I want to get the length of `modelObjects` object for example)

I got a massage:

> error: angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelObjects'
>   of undefined

This is how I use it:

```
function _getIds() {
    var path = vm.package.path;

    var SERVER_PATH = Config.SERVER_PATH;
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        $http.post(SERVER_PATH + '/getLastGetRelated', { path: vm.package.path })
            .then(
            function (success) {
                resolve(success);
            },
            function (err) {
                reject(err);
            })
    });
}   


this.camera = function() {
    _getIds().then(function(ids){
    console.log(Object.ServiceData.modelObjects.length);
    readJson(ids);
    })
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Noticed you have `Object.ServiceData` and `Object.data.ServiceData` above, which is the correct name?

Comment: You are creating a promise for something that already returns a promise, just return `$http.post()`. Also your data is in `ids` not in `Object`, meaning you would do `ids.ServiceData.modelObject`. Your first clue should have been you haven't even defined a variable named `Object`

Comment: WTH does this have to do with parsing JSON?

Answer (score 0):

> my code falls in the beginning (when i check the length) :
>
> ```
> Object.data.ServiceData.modelObjects.length;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> console.log(Object.ServiceData.modelObjects.length);
> ```

Actually, you're checking:

```
Object.ServiceData.modelObjects.length
```

and not:

```
Object.data.ServiceData.modelObjects.length;
```

The easiest way to see how your data looks like would be to temporarily change:

```
console.log(Object.ServiceData.modelObjects.length);
```

to:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object));
```

But keep in mind that `Object` is a built-in function (actually a constructor) in JavaScript so it is unlikely to contain your data.

Also, this:

```
return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            $http.post(SERVER_PATH + '/getLastGetRelated', { path: vm.package.path })
                .then(
                function (success) {
                    resolve(success);
                },
                function (err) {
                    reject(err);
                })
```

could be written as:

```
return $http.post(SERVER_PATH + '/getLastGetRelated', { path: vm.package.path });
```

General advice:

Now, if you don't want your program to crash while accessing properties that may or may not exist, you can use:

```
console.log(Object && Object.data && Object.data.ServiceData
    && Object.data.ServiceData.modelObjects
    && Object.data.ServiceData.modelObjects.length);
```

or using lodash:

```
console.log(_.get(Object, 'data.ServiceData.modelObjects.length'));
```

or using hoek:

```
console.log(hoek.reach(Object, 'data.ServiceData.modelObjects.length'));
```

See:

- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get
- https://github.com/hapijs/hoek/blob/master/API.md#reachobj-chain-options

In summary, there are a lot of problems with your code. You are most likely confused about how promises work, what data you get, in which variable and how to access the parts you need.

My advice would be to read more about promises, inspect the data that you get from the API and carefully write that code from scratch. Unfortunately no one will be able to fix that code for you in the form as it is now because we don;t know how your data looks like and what exactly do you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer to the question but i like to point out one thing. http by default returning the response as promise. But in here promise created manually to catch the response which already a promise. This is unnecessary. Just return the http request without creating new promises like this

```
function _getIds() {
    var path = vm.package.path;
    var SERVER_PATH = Config.SERVER_PATH;
    return $http.post(SERVER_PATH + '/getLastGetRelated', {
        path: vm.package.path
    })
}
this.camera = function() {
    _getIds().then(function(ids) {
        console.log(Object.ServiceData.modelObjects.length);
        readJson(ids);
    })
}
```